# How to link selected option in a selectmenu to a function (basic coding)

Tags: jquery

I'm a coding beginner. Trying to link selecting an option in a menu to a specific function.

eg. http://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/

I want to use a selectmenu as seen on the above link. However, I don't know how to take the next step and link the selected option to a specific function.

The function I want when you select an option is to be linked to another page on the site.
The function part of the code in the above site's example seems to be this:

$(function() {
    $( "#speed" ).selectmenu();

I imagine more coding needs to be added to get the function you want.

How do I make it so that selecting "Slow" from the menu (for example) links you to espn.com (for example).

A example of the specific coding for that would be appreciated! (novice)

Comment: Please read further http://api.jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#event-change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Selectmenu - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#speed" ).selectmenu();
 $('#speed').selectmenu({
    change: function() {
        if($(this).val() != '') {
            window.location.replace($(this).val());
        }
    }
});

  });
  </script>
  <style>
    fieldset {
      border: 0;
    }
    label {
      display: block;
      margin: 30px 0 0 0;
    }
    select {
      width: 200px;
    }
    .overflow {
      height: 200px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
    <select name="speed" id="speed">
      <option value="/Page1">Fast</option> 
      <option value="www.google.com">Slow</option>     
    </select>    
  </fieldset>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you perhaps be even more specific? Like say I want if you select the option "slow", you go to the website www.espn.com. How does this look exactly as a code?

Comment: If it's not too much trouble, could you give a specific example for just one of the options? Could you make it so that selecting "slow" takes you to www.google.com? I need to see a specific example to work it out, I can't figure it out with all the generic terms. Sorry for being so stupid!

Answer (score 0):

As u_mulder said you should really check out the api docs for properties and methods of jquery ui widgets. The one he has linked in the comment is to the event change which is fired whenever a menu item is changed. The code from that example is:

```
$( ".selector" ).selectmenu({
  change: function( event, ui ) {
    //put your logic in here - psuedo code below
    if(selected option === comparisonValue){
      go to page
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you perhaps be even more specific? Like say I want if you select the option "slow", you go to the website www.espn.com. How does this look exactly as a code?

Comment: I appreciate that you are having trouble but I'm not going to write all your code for you, you wont learn that way. To be more specific? Find out what you need to do and then find out how to do it. In this case you need to find out how to get the value of the select option. Then compare this select option to your comparison value, and if they match then go to espn. So for the final bit you need to find out how to "transition" to another page. Your best bet is to go off and try this and if youre having problems with YOUR OWN code then come back with specific questions. But show an effort.

Comment: If you want an introduction to jquery or javascript there are plenty of free tutorials online. codeschool, tutsplus...

Comment: I appreciate your comments. That's up to you. I learn best from seeing example of how it is actually done. Otherwise I'm struggling to work out the exact syntax of it

Comment: To be more specific, I'm finding it difficult to learn from the tutorial because I don't know which bits are the stuff I'm meant to replace. Yes I could go through a whole tutorial, but I would learn straight away if you just gave one example of what it would look like (specifically), rather than putting generic function(event (this) etc.